# Networking switch vs router connection issue

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, internet-connection, switch

This is a very simple and stupid problem but I can't get around it. I asked it on the NetworkEngineering exchange but I was recommended to post it here.

I am having an issue with one connection from a distribution-layer switch to an access-layer switch. I hope someone can point me in the right direction on how to troubleshoot this problem, since I am completely stuck. I hope the question is clear.

**The setup**

In my setup, there is a distribution-layer, **24-port switch** in a rack that gives internet access to four offices. All ports seem to be working fine.

One of the offices is far away. There is a **CAT5e Ethernet cable of about 80m that runs from the switch on the rack to an 8-port switch at the office**. There are two computers and an IP phone in this office connected to that switch.

**The issue**

As it is, the connection between the racked switch and the 8-port switch doesn't work. I've tried all the 24 ports of the first switch (which I'm sure work fine) and tried replacing the 8 port switch. Nothing works. There is no activity light in the connected ports.

Connecting a single device directly to the 24-port switch works. So the cable doesn't seem to be the problem.

**The only thing that solved the issue is replacing the 8-port switch with a cheap router (connected as a switch, with all cables connected to LAN ports, WAN port unconnected). That works just fine.**

So please, does anyone know why would the connection work with a router but not with a switch? I am completely perplexed and would welcome any suggestions.

In any case, should I replace the 24-port switch? I sense the problem will still persist but is something I could try.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Do the *link* lights on the switches turn on when the cable is plugged? Not all switches support Auto MDI-X, so you might need a crossover cable or adapter.

Comment: We can't know for sure without model number(s) but as zac67 suggests, the router is possibly auto-sensing uplink while the 3 switches tested do not. This is the most likely explanation for the question "why this router" ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium-dependent_interface )

Comment: I'll bet you that the cable is mis-wired. Most likely, the pins-to-pairs mapping is incorrect and the router just happens to be more tolerant than the switch.

Comment: Hi guys I just saw your comments. Thanks so much for the advice! I guess you'd suggest the same as Tonny on the answer below, trying to place a cross cable in between to see if the MDI-X is failing. I'll try and see how it turns out!

Answer (score 1):

A switch is not a router. You need a router to convert the ISP Modem signal (DSL, Cable, Fiber) to TCP/IP that your devices need.

A router often includes a switch (4, 8, 16 port router with included switch).

A simple switch just distributes packets from input to multiple outputs.

You can connect (cascade) switches together to provide more ports. Mostly (not always) you can connect a LAN port from one switch to a LAN port on the first switch. Check your switch documentation.

A more complicated managed switch may also be smart switch for managing many devices and VLAN capabilities for separating networks into different segments.

But in simple terms a switch is not a router which is why your first setup does not have Internet.

Your switch may be defective but that does not seem overly likely. Just make sure it is connected properly.

Substitute another switch to test and to be certain.

> So the cable doesn't seem to be the problem.

Still do not overlook cables. Easy to substitute new ones.

Comment: The 24-port switch is behind another switch, that is behind the router that routes LAN traffic to the internet. The setup I described is all in the LAN, far from the main gateway. The router that I'm adding is connected as a switch, i.e. the WAN port unconnected.

Comment: Make sure the switch hookup is correct.  Switches can be connected.  Check the switch ports and documentation for proper connection (possible uplink port). Your question was router vs. switch which I answered. But if you are cascading switches behind a router, that can be done.

Comment: I filled out my answer to included testing with another switch (not a router) to test the first switch.

Comment: I will try substituting the 24-port switch in the next few days. Thanks John. I feel it might be a cable issue though, I read somewhere that crappy cables can cause different devices to behave differently. That will be the second thing to try. Thanks

Comment: You had said you did not think it was a cable (so I did not add that to troubleshooting) but do try.

Comment: Yes I was first reluctant to think the cable was the problem, but then seeing some related questions on reddit and then the answer Tonny gave below... I start to believe the problem is there.

Comment: I added cable check to my answer a while ago.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to check the cable. 80 meter for CAT5e is in theory fine, but in practice...
How long has that cable been there? A year? 5 years? 10 years? Older cables can degrade over time.
Some devices are more sensitive to that than others so that may explain why the PC did connect and the router, but the other switch not.

But more likely is the second problem:
That is the duplex and speed settings and whether or not you are dealing with a straight or a cross-over connection.
Gigabit ports are usually configured for auto-negotiate and auto-mdx (actually the Gigabit standard requires that as default). But that only works properly if BOTH ends of the connection use that setting AND the signal quality is decent.
100 Mb/s ports have auto-negotiate as well, but auto-mdx is not so common.
When it doesn't work properly you either get no connection at all (no link-LED's) or a connection that is flooded with collision errors (link-LED's are on, but it still doesn't work properly).

Since the router and PC work (both of which should default to auto-negotiate and auto-mdx) I'm guessing that the 24-port switch also uses auto-negotiate, but the 8-port switch doesn't (or it is not doing auto-mdx which isn't unusual for a switch).

Please note: Sometimes no amount of auto-negotiate/auto-mdx settings is ever going to work for specific combinations of hardware. In that case you have to configure the switch-port manually on BOTH ends to the same speed,  full-duplex and set the MDI setting on one end to normal and the other side to cross (presuming the 80 meter cable is a straight cable).
Between 2 switches you always need 1 cross connection. Either configured by auto-mdx, configured manually in the switches, or by having a cross-cable somewhere between the switches.

Comment: Thanks Tonny that is excellent advice! I will try placing a cross cable in between and see how it goes. Thanks!